# Ansible template loop variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have three hosts in my invenotry file to configure HAPROXY setup. using below ansible tempalte I was able populate the IP address in the configurtion file. I also want to change the name with index value. how can I change kube-1 to variable like (kube-1, kube-2, kube-3)

**template**

```
{% for host in groups['master'] %}
        server kube-1 {{ hostvars[host]["ansible_default_ipv4"]["address"] }}:30549 check verify none
{% endfor %}
```

**sample output**

```
server kube-1 x.x.x.x:30549 check verify none
server kube-1 x.x.x.x:30549 check verify none
server kube-1 x.x.x.x:30549 check verify none
```

**Required output**

```
server kube-1 x.x.x.x:30549 check verify none
server kube-2 x.x.x.x:30549 check verify none
server kube-3 x.x.x.x:30549 check verify none
```

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `loop.index` variable available inside a `for` control structure in jinja2. The following should meet your expectations.

```
{% for host in groups['master'] %}
        server kube-{{ loop.index }} {{ hostvars[host]["ansible_default_ipv4"]["address"] }}:30549 check verify none
{% endfor %}
```

Ref: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for